# how can i destuct last logging object in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

Consider:

```
import logging
In [6]: def foo():
   ...:     logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARNING)
   ...:     logging.warning("logging message 1")
   ...:     logging.shutdown()
   ...: def bar():
   ...:     logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARNING, format="%(asctime)-15s %(
   ...: levelname)-8s %(message)s")
   ...:     logging.warning("logging message 2")
   ...:     

In [7]: foo()
WARNING:root:logging message 1

In [8]: bar()
WARNING:root:logging message 2
```

but i expect to see:

```
In [7]: foo()
WARNING:root:logging message 1
In [8]: bar()
2020-02-29 01:42:54,995 WARNING  logging message 2
```

my point is that in the second function i expect to have new logging object with new format but it is the first function logging object with it's format.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that. Try adding `force=True` to the `basicConfig`  but `shutdown` specifically warns _This should be called at application exit and no further use of the logging system should be made after this call._

Comment: Regarding `shutdown`: "Informs the logging system to perform an orderly shutdown by flushing and closing all handlers. This should be called at application exit and **no further use of the logging system should be made after this call.**"

Answer (score -1):

Add `logging.getLogger().handlers = []` at the end of foo to get the desired result. Shutdown doesn't reset the logging system, it just cleans it up for exiting.